# What is alternative of HttpCookie, CookieManager classes in API level 8

Tags: android, android-networking

I am using HttpCookie, CookieManager, CookieStore classes in my project but as they are available only in API level 9. As soon as I changed to api level8, I am getting lint errors. Please let me know what is the alternative.

Call requires API level 9 (current min is 8): java.net.HttpCookie#getName

Comment: Why are you working on API8?  8 is less than .1% of all devices in use:  http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html.  You definitely shouldn't be supporting anything lower than 9, and I wouldn't suggest lower than 15.

Comment: Yes but we need to support some legacy app which are using API level 8